# I get this error while trying to run pip install pyAudio in my pyCharm venv running on windows 10

Tags: python-3.x

> (venv) C:\Users\Jaymoh\PycharmProjects\Elisanta>pip install PyAudio
>   Collecting PyAudio   Using cached
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/42/b4f04721c5c5bfc196ce156b3c768998ef8c0ae3654ed29ea5020c749a6b/PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz
>   Installing collected packages: PyAudio   Running setup.py install for
>   PyAudio ... error
>       Complete output from command C:\Users\Jaymoh\PycharmProjects\Elisanta\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u -c
>   "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\Jaymoh\AppData\Local\Temp
>   \pip-install-sp8mdmpo\PyAudio\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open',
>   open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --
>   record
>   C:\Users\Jaymoh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-jxykmy44\install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers C:\Users\Jaymoh\PycharmProjects\Elisa
>   nta\venv\include\site\python3.7\PyAudio:
>       running install
>       running build
>       running build_py
>       creating build
>       creating build\lib.win32-3.7
>       copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7
>       running build_ext
>       building '_portaudio' extension
>       creating build\temp.win32-3.7
>       creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release
>       creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src
>       C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe
>   /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\Jaymoh\PycharmProje
>   cts\Elisanta\venv\include
>   -IC:\Users\Jaymoh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\include -IC:\Users\Jaymoh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\include"
>   "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um"
>   /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\
>   temp.win32-3.7\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
>       _portaudiomodule.c
>       src/_portaudiomodule.c(27): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdio.h': No such file or directory
>       error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe'
>   failed with exit status 2
>
> ---------------------------------------- Command "C:\Users\Jaymoh\PycharmProjects\Elisanta\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u
>   -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\Jaymoh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-sp8mdmpo\
>   PyAudio\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open',
>   open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record C:\Users\Jaymoh\A ppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-jxykmy44\install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers C:\Users\Jaymoh\PycharmProjects\Elisanta\venv\include\site\py
>   thon3.7\PyAudio" failed with error code 1 in
>   C:\Users\Jaymoh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-sp8mdmpo\PyAudio\

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Try editing your question, and use the format features in the toolbar to format the error messages as code blocks to make them more readable. Also, it is very helpful to provide as much information as you can about your situation. For example, is this the first time you installed pyAudio? What version of pip are you using (pip --version)? More details would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Simply install `pipwin` 
by `pip install pipwin`
and the run

```
pipwin install pyaudio
```

Answer (score -2):

Download windows 10 sdk from vs buildtools and this should help you.
Download Link:https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017
click on free download